# Merging multiple Backbone View $el into one jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, backbone.js

I would like this to appear in the DOM:

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>This is 1</li>
    <li>This is 2</li>
    <li>This is 3</li>
    <li>This is 4</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

`ul` is **parentView** and `li` is **subView**. This is how I want it to work:

1. **parentView** will initialize and create **subView** in simple for() loop as an example.
2. I don't want to render each of the **subView** creation in **addSub** so I just return the jQuery object `$el` of **subView**.
3. **parentView** will save these `$el` and merge them in a single jQuery object such as `$new`. I use jQuery function `.add()` for this.
4. Then once the loop is done, render the `$new` to the DOM. So everything must happen outside of the DOM.

Right now my code doesn't work. It doesn't show anything. What did I did wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/nTTbH/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things are incorrect here. In your ParentView, your code:

```
    for (i=1;i<=4;i++) {
        $new.add(this.addSub(i));
    }

    this.$el.html($new.html());
```

`$new.add(this.addSub(i))`is not being saved due to the nature of how of .add() works. You would need to change this line to something along the lines of `$new = $new.add(this.addSub(i))`; to make it work.

I would suggest to avoid using this approach altogether and have a look at using .append to add your li's to your ul on each iteration.

e.g. `this.$el.append(this.addSub(i))` or `this.$el.append(this.addSub(i).render().el)`

Again, your usage of .add() leads to your `$el.html($new.html())`, but this is unnecessary as $new by itself will be your 4 li elements so you can just call $new itself with `this.$el.html($new);`

Lastly, you need to set your "root" element in your parentView, remove `tagName: ul` and it should be `el: ul` as it needs something to set your subViews onto

Here is an updated jsfiddle of your code working here: http://jsfiddle.net/SQFwg/

If you take away anything away from this, it's to not use .add() and use .append() instead!

Comment: If I use .append(), it will render in each loop which is inefficient. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SQFwg/1/. But your suggested code using .add() works though.